# Net Core: Difference between .SetBasePath and .UseContentRoot in Startup.Cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

What is the difference between .SetBasePath and .UseContentRoot in Startup configuration?

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();
```

[How can I use IConfiguration from my integration tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46269931/how-can-i-use-iconfiguration-from-my-integration-tests)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`SetBasePath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.fileconfigurationextensions.setbasepath?view=aspnetcore-2.2) is an extension method for `IConfigurationBuilder`, which sets the path to use when locating configuration files:

> Sets the FileProvider for file-based providers to a PhysicalFileProvider with the base path.

For example, when locating the `appsettings.json` file you've specified in your question, it will look in the path retrieved using `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`

[`UseContentRoot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.hostingabstractionswebhostbuilderextensions.usecontentroot?view=aspnetcore-2.2) is an extension method for `IWebHostBuilder`, which sets the [`contentRoot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-2.2#content-root) key for the Web Host:

> This setting determines where ASP.NET Core begins searching for content files, such as MVC views.

The default value used for the `contentRoot` key is:

> [...] the folder where the app assembly resides.

This means that, for a typical setup, the path for both will end up being the same, but this is not a requirement.

Answer (score 2):

For dotnet6/7 in 2022 with top-level statements, `UseContentRoot` is not available, just set the current directory before `WebApplication.CreateBuilder` works for me.

```
var dllFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(dllFolder);

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Configuration.SetBasePath(dllFolder);
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. `Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(System.AppContext.BaseDirectory);` worked for me in a .net 6 console app where I don't have the `WebApplication`.