# Class fixture type 'XXXX.HomeController' had one or more unresolved constructor arguments: ILogger`1 logger, IConfiguration configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xunit

I am using Xunit and try to unit test this HomeController , currently using .NET 6

```
  public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
    public readonly IConfiguration Configuration;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }


    public IActionResult AppSetting()
    {
        string JsonKey1 = Configuration["MyGlobalVar:Key1"];
        return Content(JsonKey1);
    }


}
```

This is my unit test code

```
public class HomeControllerTest : IClassFixture<HomeController>
{
  
    HomeController _homeController;

    public HomeControllerTest(HomeController homeController)
    {
        _homeController=homeController;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test_Index_ReturnViewName()
    {
        var result = _homeController.Index() as ViewResult;
        Assert.Equal("Index",result?.ViewName);

    }
```

Anyone know how to fix the error?

Comment: xUnit cannot know how to resolve constructor parameter dependencies (ILogger and IConfiguration). Somewhere you will have to create these dependencies and pass them to the constructor of your controller class.

Comment: What's the reason to use IClassFixture anyways? Do you really want to share the same objects between tests? Because this can easily lead to unwanted side effects.

Comment: If you just want to share the same objects in all Tests of the same Test class simply create a field of your system under test (HomeController) and new it up with some logger and configuration objects (maybe a mocked object) as parameters. You can then use the field of HomeController in each test and xUnit will automatically create a fresh instance of it on each test run.

Comment: You should create a new `HomeController` in each test, otherwise, your tests can quickly become brittle. Consider the situation where one test changes the state of your object, and makes subsequent tests work differently. Do not overuse `IClassFixture`.

Comment: afh/Davide , do you mind show some sample code on how to fix the error?

Comment: MarwaAhmad [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46269931/how-can-i-use-iconfiguration-from-my-integration-tests) solved the error.

Answer (score 0):

This is what @DavidG means:

```
public class HomeControllerTest
{
    public HomeControllerTest()
    {
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test_Index_ReturnViewName()
    {
        // Arrange
        HomeController _homeController = new HomeController();
        // Act
        var result = _homeController.Index() as ViewResult;
        // Assert
        Assert.Equal("Index",result?.ViewName);
    }
}
```

If there is no compelling reason that each test has to use the same instance of `HomeController` then you should create a new one in each test.

Comment: Hi Chris , thank for the sample code. My HomeController take in 2 arguments ( ILogger<HomeController> logger, IConfiguration configuration) , check the above HomeController > constructor code section . Current provided sample code will throw missing constructor arguments error , that is what I try to fix here...

Comment: Same principle applies to them then: if there's no compelling reason to use the same instances in all the tests, make new instances of ``ILogger<HomeController>`` and  ``IConfiguration`` in the "Arrange" section and use them in the ``HomeController`` constructor.  Any class you specify in an ``IClassFixture<T>`` declaration must have a _parameterless_ public constructor.